# Is it safe to compare two doubles using <= or >= operators?

Tags: java, language-agnostic

I understand that it's not correct to compare two doubles using `==` operator. But is it safe to compare two doubles like `<=` or `>=`?

Comment: The correct way to compare doubles and floats in Java : https://howtodoinjava.com/java-examples/correctly-compare-float-double/

Answer (score -2):

Actually it depends on your need. Of course `==` operator is not at all safe with `double` data type. But using operators like `<=` and `>=` might not suit your need. So instead, you can convert double into float data type and then check. I know that it will not provide you precision but that's the way you have to do.

Those wondering why `==` is not safe, try out

```
System.out.println(0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3);
```

and you will get output as `false`.

Comment: Let me get this straight: since comparing `double`s is not precise we should convert them to `float`s so we lower the precision even further?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca So that's what you want right. You don't want unnecessary precision. Try the example stated by me above and you'll get to know what am I talking about. Also watch : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken